# Probablistic approach

Tags: probability-theory

I have been reading about probabilistic approach in some problems in particular when we want to prove that something exists without explicitly constructing it. I really want to see more of this. Does anyone know a good book/paper/any kind of material where I could find different examples with this probabilistic method?

Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 1):

[*The Probabilistic Method*](http://www.cs.nyu.edu/spencer/nogabook/nogabook.html), by Alon and Spencer, would be the reference you're looking for.